# The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found.error while try to build using pipeline jenkinsfile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, github, build, jenkins-pipeline

i have tried another docker files to make the build work nothing helps.. iam using asp.net-mvc5

errors when i try to build from jenkins:

```
Restore completed in 2.44 sec for /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Team21/jobs/Project/workspace/WebAppTest/WebAppTest.csproj.

/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Team21/jobs/Project/workspace/WebApplication2/WebApplication2.csproj(482,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Team21/jobs/Project/workspace/WebApplication2//MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.203/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1183,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Team21/jobs/Project/workspace/WebAppTest/WebAppTest.csproj]



Build FAILED.



    0 Warning(s)

    2 Error(s)
```

the pipeline jenkins file iam using:

```
pipeline {
     //Use the following docker image to run your dotnet app.
     agent { docker { image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.203- 
  alpine'} }

     environment {HOME = '/tmp'} 
     stages {

     // Get some code from a GitHub repository
       stage('Git') {
       steps{
          git 'https://github.com/user/project.git'
      }
     }
   //     stage('Dotnet Restore'){
    //      steps{
          //  sh "dotnet restore"
      //    }
      // }

     stage('Build') {
     steps {
     sh "dotnet build"
    }
  }
   stage('Unit Tests') {
    steps {
      sh 'dotnet test'
    }
    }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is offering you the answer:

> To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework
>   version

You are missing the correct framework for the task you want to execute on your Jenkins so you have to install it.

Comment: Did you install .net 4.6.1? Maybe you have to restart the agent.

Comment: yeah i did.. how can i restart the agent?

Comment: Maybe you should try a different docker image. What about this: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet? It says it contains multiple .net frameworks

Comment: i tried that and many more... i dont think it's a docker problem// something is missing in the server that involves msbuild.